# How can I shift queue commands to a group of meepos?

Tags: dota-2

Being used to microing, I'm learning to play Meepo. However, I've encountered some difficulties when it came to queue commands.

How do I shift-queue commands to a group of meepos?

**Quick example :**

I'm roaming with my main meepo, and my meepo clones are in the fountain but I want to send all of them to walk and then "poof" a jungle camp, how do I do that? I'm already familiar with tabbing through the control group, can I apply the same technique to a group but just hold shift for the duration i.e. select all meepos, click to move them to the camp, then hold shift and press 'w', left click, tab, 'w', left click tab etc for all meepos? Or is it trickier ?

Comment: You're right. This way you'll move to the desired location, then you'll queue the poof command to be used after you reach the desired camp. I didn't add this as an answer because perhaps someone else can give you detailed info on how to do this better.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the thanks but try to keep your question as neutral as possible. Try to go to the point and you can still left a comment to show your appreciation of an answer. For your question  , I don't play much micro heavy heroes. I'll take a look.

Comment: Noted for future posts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To shift-queue the command in the way you are describing, it gets a bit trickier than that. Holding shift while selecting a group of Meepos will only queue a command for the first Meepo of the current group. If you want to shift queue an action for each of them you have to do it the following way :

- Send the group (walking for example) wherever you want
- Hold Shift
- Queue action for the first Meepo
- release Shift
- Tab to the second one
- Hold Shift
- Queue action for the second Meepo >
- release Shift
- Tab to the third one
- Keep going for all your Meepos

Answer (score 1):

You can also enable "hold cltrl to command all units" in options, this lets you do ctrl+shift + command to make all meepos follow a command.